# Any possible way to prolong Facebook token server-side when offline_access permission will be deprecated

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I read Facebook article about offline_access deprecation and I read that “Apps will not be able to setup a background/cron job that tries to automatically extend the expiration time”, but this is not acceptable for our application and I need to find the way how to prolong access token server-side automatically. The single solution I’m seeing now is to keep real login / password for Facebook accounts and do automatic Facebook authentication for each account to prolong the access token.
I don’t like this idea, but I can’t find anything better. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: So far that's the only way.. But IMO, there's already a few cases in the news about employers asking for Facebook passwords, and making it mandatory for certain apps they might use could make the situation worse.